# Too many features selected with the ArcMap Select by Polygon tool

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, sdo-geometry

I have ArcMap 10.1 SP1. My features are stored in Oracle 11g database in SDO_GEOMETRY format.

I have imported a layer of accidents location in ArcMap. So when I try to select all features included in a polygon (using the Select by Polygon), then too many features are selected. I mean some feature outside my polygon are part of selected feature.

I draw a triangle on my map and I expect that all features included into the triangle will be selected. The result I obtain is all features included in the rectangle envelope of the triangle that are selected, which is obvious wrong.

Is someone can help me on this one?

I was in SDE_GEOMETRY before and I did not have the problem when I tried to select by polygon.

[image: Here is my polygon selection (triangle)]

[image: This is the wrong result of the polygon selection]

[image: The rectangle envelope that seems to be used by ArcMap]

Comment: Are there multipart features? That could cause that behaviour.

Comment: Thanks but actually it's not a multipart point layer.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this behavior several times previously. Once was a bad coordinate system combination between map and data (map in AGD66 and data in MGA) and the second time was indexing on the SDE database.

Ensure map and data are in the same coordinate system (or at least datum) and if the problem persists try reindexing the database if that option is available to you.